# Saving a deleted Powershell script

Tags: powershell, recovery

I accidently deleted several Powershell scripts from the command line, and recovery tools have not been successful in recovering them.  As it happens, the two most important scripts were running at the time of deletion (in a normal Powershell prompt rather than ISE), and they are still running normally.  Is it possible to recover these two scripts from memory?

Comment: In theory, yes. In practice, well, that's another matter. Start with [`procdump -ma`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sysinternals/downloads/procdump) and start spelunking; if you're lucky enough the script might be a contiguous Unicode string.

Comment: Do you have access to the prompt in those running shells? You can access all cached scriptblocks via reflection...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerShell [caches the result](https://blog.iisreset.me/recovering-scripts-from-the-scriptblock-cache/) every time it compiles a scriptblock from a script file, and then indexes the compiled blocks by script name/path and contents - so we can extract the raw scripts that have already been run in a given host application with a bit of reflection:

```
function Get-ScriptBlockCache {
    # Internal variable name changed in PowerShell core, take into account
    $fieldName = '_cachedScripts'
    if($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major -ge 6){
      $fieldName = 's_cachedScripts'
    }

    # Obtain type metadata for the field we want to extract values from
    $cachedScriptsMemberInfo = [scriptblock].GetMember($fieldName, 'Static,NonPublic')[0]
    
    # We're only interested in the keys, since they contain the original script text
    return @($cachedScriptsMemberInfo.GetValue($null).Keys) |Select @{Name='Path';Expression='Item1'},@{Name='ScriptSourceCode';Expression='Item2'}
}
```

Now you can do:

```
Get-ScriptBlockCache |Where-Object Path -like "*nameOfDeletedScript.ps1" |ForEach-Object ScriptSourceCode
```

#### What if you don't have prompt access?

In case the process is running unattended (eg. as a scheduled task or run with `-File` and with `-NoExit`), you can use PowerShell's amazing debugging facilities to carve out a secondary runspace in the target process and run the cache recovery from there:

```
Enter-PSHostProcess -Id <targetProcessId>
# Once you're dropped into the target process, define the `Get-ScriptBlockCache` function and execute it
```

#### What if the process has already exited?

If the process is no longer running, then the *cache is lost too* - but there's another option: ScriptBlock logs!

If the machine is configured with mandatory script block logging enabled, you can also fetches any script or scriptblock PowerShell has parsed from the event log (providing the log entry hasn't been overwritten yet):

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName='Microsoft-Windows-PowerShell/Operational';Id=4104} |Select TimeCreated,@{Name='SourceCode';Expression={$_.Properties[2].Value}}
```

This won't show process id or script path/name, but if you know which time it executed and have a rough idea of the scripts contents, you should be able to glean it from those logs :)

---

**Note**: The script block cache extraction trick only works in ISE if you invoked the script from disk, eg `& path\to\script.ps1` - scripts opened in the editor pane and executed directly within ISE will not have been cached in this fashion.

Comment: I assume that I will need to have access to the particular Powershell prompt windows in order for this to work?  The scripts are running, but there is no option to exit gracefully to a prompt - they close the window if I Ctrl-C out, for instance.

Comment: @MichaelH You can access a running process from a different one (assuming same user/security context): `Enter-PSHostProcess -Id <processIdOfTargetPowerShellProcess>`, then define and run the `Get-ScriptBlockCache` from there.

Comment: Words cannot express my gratitude to you right now.  You, my good wizard, have saved my bacon in a MAJOR way.  One of my scripts ended up closed, so I'm guessing it's lost, but the other one (and the more important one, I might add) was still running.  I went through your process and got the whole thing back!!!!  THANK YOU!!!!  :D

Comment: @MichaelH You're most welcome! FWIW, there's another possibility of recovering the second script _if script block logging is enabled on the machine_. I'll update the answer

Comment: @MichaelH: Do note that you are exceptionally lucky with PowerShell even having `Enter-PSHostProcess`. With just about anything else a raw memory dump would have been your only recourse. :P (The latter *might* still work for retrieving the other script, incidentally, depending on the managed heap.)

Comment: I did actually try the memory dump, but I haven't the faintest idea what I'm doing.  I still have the dump files (pulled via PROCDUMP.EXE), but have no idea how to pull anything useful out of them.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks do the indexing scheme in the cache (raw source code string as partial key), `!dumpheap` should indeed let you fetch the original script (but it'll probably be a bit more cumbersome to script in WinDBG than doing it like this :-P)

Comment: @MichaelH I've updated the answer with an example of how to query the PowerShell ScriptBlock log events

Comment: @MichaelH: you can use something like [`strings -u`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sysinternals/downloads/strings) to scan the output for a part of the script that you know, and get the rest from the context. Although scanning the heap with WinDbg would be more reliable, that's a little more ambitious. :P